# How to create sqlalchemy class with child/parent to json?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

I have this model in SQLAlchemy,i going to convert this model to json model with relationship

```
class Test(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'reltest'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(50))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('reltest.id'),index=True)
    children = relationship(lambda: Student, remote_side=[id])
    hashid = None
```

Query SelectAll:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=ConnectEngine())
sessiondb = Session()
c = sessiondb.query(Student).all() ?? ## How to Convert List Object To JSON
```

how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been so long you asked this question.Probably this might be useful who stumble on this

```
from json import JSONEncoder, dumps

class DatabaseObjectEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Base):
            return o.get_dict()
        return super(DatabaseObjectEncoder, self).default(o)
    def json_encode_db_obj(obj):
        return dumps(obj, cls=DatabaseObjectEncoder)


    Session = sessionmaker(bind=ConnectEngine())
    sessiondb = Session()
    c = json_encode_db_obj(sessiondb.query(Student).all()) # c should have a json now
```